# Duplicate None or other Python sigletons

Tags: python

First of all: This question covers practically zero use cases, and is only about morbid curiosity. That being said:

I started wondering not so long ago if it was possible to duplicate the `None` object from Python (or any other singleton like `True` or `Ellipsis`). By "duplicate", I mean create an exact copy that is not another reference to the same object. That is:

```
>>> noneBis == None
True
>>> noneBis is None
False
```

Why I think this would be possible, is because of the core philosophy of Python: ***Everything is an object***. And an object can be copied.

I have tried several ways (some more convoluted than others) and couldn't do it:

```
>>> copy.deepcopy(None) is None
True
>>> types.NoneType()
TypeError: cannot create NoneType instances
>>> object.__new__(type(None))
TypeError: object.__new__(NoneType) is not safe, use NoneType.__new__()
>>> types.NoneType.__new__(types.NoneType)
TypeError: object.__new__(NoneType) is not safe, use NoneType.__new__()
```

This seems pretty hardened and mad-scientist-proof to me, but I am not sure I have tried hard enough. (I have tested this in Python 2.7, but since Python 3+ have been designed to be even more foolproof than Python 2, my guess is the results won't be better.)

**Can you actually create a separate duplicate of a Python singleton?**

Comment: Well, if your definition of "duplicate" is simply `noneBis == None and noneBis is not None`, then you just need to create a class with an appropriate `__eq__` method.

Comment: `class NotNone: def __eq__(self, other): return other == None`…

Comment: "Why I think this would be possible, is because of the core philosophy of Python: Everything is an object. And an object can be copied." => Who ever said that an object could be copied ? Chapter and verse please ?-)

Comment: You want to *imitate the behaviour* of `None`; cloning `None` isn't necessary for that. The correct mantra here is the one about duck typing.

Comment: For True/False you can use `numpy.True_` and `numpy.False_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could create a "duplicate copy" of a singleton, it wouldn't really be a singleton anymore, would it ?

wrt/ builtin singletons (like `None`) which are implemented in C (or whatever the language for a given implementation), I don't think you can ever expect to "clone" them except by either fork Python or some similarly extreme method. Also note that since the Python language specs explicitely garantees that `None` is a singleton, this wouldn't be Python anymore ;)

Now if all you want is something that is a singleton and compares equal to `None` while not being `None`, here's a possible (python 2.7.x) implementation:

```
def __mknone():
    _instance = [None]

    class NotNoneType(object):
        def __new__(cls):
            if _instance[0] is not None:
                raise TypeError("cannot create 'NotNoneType' instances")
            _instance[0] =  object.__new__(cls)
            return _instance[0]

        def __eq__(self, other):
            if other is None:
                return True
            return other == _instance[0]

        def __nonzero__(self):
            return False

    return NotNoneType()

NotNone = __mknone()
NotNoneType = type(NotNone)
del __mknone
```

Tell me if you manage to create another instance of `NotNoneType` BTW ;)

Comment: Do the python language specs also guarantee that for `True`, `False`, or `Ellipsis`? (My guess: not in python 2, yes in python 3, based on being able to say `True = False`) Where is that guarantee made for `None`, anyway?

Comment: According to the official language spec, `None`, `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` are guaranteed to be singletons. This is true for both 2.7.x and 3.6.x:   https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy   https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy